# PERL - Multithreading - Children + grandchildren - limit of threads running

Tags: multithreading, perl

I have made a Perl script where I create threads (limited in terms of threads running in the meantime) and each threads create its own children which should be also limited in number.

Where I host my script, I cannot launch more than X threads per Perl script in the meantime. In the below example, I have X = 3 x 7 = 21 threads maximum in the meantime.

- 3 for the 1st job (`$nb_process_first`)
- 7 for the 2nd job (`$nb_process_second`)

Questions:

1. Is there a better way to manage threads and their children? (queues for example - could you please bring me some code example because I have tried with no success)
2. My current script is not terminating with all the threads joined, although I use a loop on all running threads to join them (cf. at the end of the script).

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -s

use threads;

my @threads;
my $nb_process_first = 3;
my @running          = ();

print "START" . "\n";

$current = 1;
while ( $current <= 10 ) {
    @running = threads->list(threads::running);
    if ( scalar @running < $nb_process_first ) {
        print "Launch firstJob=" . scalar @running . "\n";
        my $thread = threads->create( \&firstJob );
        push( @threads, $thread );
    } else {
        redo;
    }
    $current++;
}

my @joinable = threads->list(threads::joinable);
while ( scalar @joinable != 0 ) {
    foreach my $thr ( threads->list() ) {
        $thr->join();
    }
    @joinable = threads->list(threads::joinable);
}

print "END" . "\n";

sub secondJob {
    for ( $i = 0; $i <= 15; $i++ ) {
        print "secondJob=" . $i . "\n";
        sleep 1;
    }
    threads->exit();
}

sub firstJob {
    my $nb_process_second = 7;
    my @running           = ();
    $current = 1;
    while ( $current <= 10 ) {
        @running = threads->list(threads::running);
        if ( scalar @running < $nb_process_second ) {
            print "firstJob/Launch secondJob=" . scalar @running . "-" . $current . "\n";
            my $secondthread = threads->create( \&secondJob );
            push( @threads, $secondthread );
            sleep 2;
        }
        $current++;
    }
    threads->exit();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Thread::Queue` is a handy model for basic 'worker thread' model of threaded code.

It goes a bit like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use threads;
use Thread::Queue;

my $firstworkitem_q = Thread::Queue -> new();
my $secondworkitem_q = Thread::Queue -> new();
my $nthreads = 10; 

sub first_worker {
   while ( my $item = $firstworkitem_q -> dequeue() ) {
       print "First worker picked up $item, and queues it to second worker\n";
       $secondworkitem_q -> enqueue ( $item ); 
   }
}

sub second_worker {
   while ( my $item = $secondworkitem_q -> dequeue() ) {
       print "Second worker got $item"; 
   }
}

my @first_workers;
for ( 1..$nthreads ) {
    my $thr = threads -> create ( \&first_worker );
    push ( @first_workers, $thr );
}

for ( 1..$nthreads ) {
    my $thr = threads -> create ( \&second_worker );
}

$firstworkitem_q -> enqueue ( @things_to_processs );
$firstworkitem_q -> end;

foreach my $firstworker ( @first_workers ) {
   $firstworker -> join();
}

#here all the first workers have finished, so we know nothing will be queued to second work queue. 
$secondworkitem_q -> end();

foreach my $thr ( threads -> list() ) {
    $thr -> join();
}
```

You stuff things into the queue, and iterate on it for processing. When you `end` the queue, the while loop gets an `undef` and thus terminates - making your thread joinable.

You don't need to track `@running` the way you do, because `threads -> list()` will do that. And more importantly - you'd need to make @running a shared variable and lock it, because otherwise you've got a different copy of it in each thread.

Having `firstJob` spawn `secondJob` I'd steer away from, because it can create all manner of fruity bugs. I'd suggest spawning two classes of worker thread. Use `$queue -> end()` to trigger the first set of workers to close.

Comment: Thank you very Much Sobrique for your input. I have few questions regarding this code sample in order to be sure that I have understood it well. 1) I do not understand what is put in the queue of the first workers : should the list things_to_processs be this list of workers first_workers ? 2) I do not understand this line my $thr = threads -> create ( \&worker ); Why do not we create threads -> create ( \&first_worker ); ? 3) I do not understand where the second workers threads are created ? I hope you do not mind, english is not my first language, I hope my questions r not rude.

Comment: Even with some of the "maybe fixes", I speak about in my previous comment, script is not running properly. If you can help me with a proper one. Thanks. for instance : Can't locate object method "end" via package "Thread::Queue"

Comment: That create - typo. Should be first_worker. Edited. If 'end' isn't found, update `Thread::Queue`. `perl -MCPAN -e shell` `install Thread::Queue`.

Comment: the list `@things_to_process` is whatever you're feeding into your threads to 'do'. If you're fetching a list of userIds to from your database, that won't parallelize well, but if you have multiple databases - you might feed the locations into the queue, and then pass the returned user ids into the second queue.

Comment: You're right - I didn't start the second worker threads. Code edited. (You can change the size of the 'for' loops if you need).

Comment: Thank you. I will have a deep look into it and revert back asap :)

Comment: I understand from that sample that there are always 2 x threads alive, aren't there ? Is it better than creating the second threads from the first bunch of threads ?

Comment: No, the sample above starts `$nthreads` of each - so 10 'first workers' and 10 'second workers'. They stay alive whilst the queue has items in. `dequeue` will block until a work item arrives. Once the queue is `end`ed it'll return `undef` break out the `while` loop, and the threads will terminate as soon as they finish processing whatever they were working on.

Comment: Thank you for this explanation. I have a question regarding stuff we can set into the @things_to_process list. while(my ATids = $sth->fetchrow_array()) {
 my $id = $ids[0];
 ATrequest = ($id, $info1, $info2, $info3, $info4, $info5);
 push (ATthings_to_process, ATrequest); 
}
$firstworkitem_q -> enqueue(ATthings_to_process); does not work

Comment: I understand that a list of list is not possible into things_to_process

Comment: Skip that push, and just `enqueue` it. A `Thread::Queue` is essentially a shared/locking array anyway.

Comment: Hi Sobrique, Do you know how to simulate end() method on a queue. Thread::Queue package on my host provider is not the last version and this method does not exist.

Comment: Best answer: update `Thread::Queue` by running `cpan install Thread::Queue`. As a crude workaround: `for ( 1..$nthreads ) { $firstworkitem_q -> enqueue ( undef ); }`

Answer (score 0):

As for your second question, threads are only joinable if they have finished running (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11122568/1919238)).  Because some of the threads aren't done when the second `while` loop runs, it finishes without joining them.

Your loop should wait based on the number of active threads, not the number of joinable threads.  Something like this:

```
while (threads->list() > 0)
{
   foreach my $joinable (threads->list(threads::joinable))
   {
       $joinable->join();
   }
}
```

As for the first question, there are certainly other ways to manage threads.  However, it is not possible to say what you should do without knowing your task.

Comment: 1st : I get an array of users from my DB, for each users I launch a bunch of threads to get personal info and for each of these personal infos I launch a 2nd bunch of threads to get others info depending on these personal info firstly received...

Comment: @Seb, from this description, it is not clear that you should be using threads at all.  What does the task "get personal info" involve?

Comment: * First threads are in charge of getting a list of ids in my database linked to the current user they are in charge of. I use a DBI connection to get those ids.

* Second threads, launched by the first threads, are used to request an intranet site where we have personal information for each ids (my $request = HTTP::Request->new(GET => $url); where $url is an intranet url with a parameter set with the ids received from my first threads).

Comment: Schematically :
Get users from DB --> get a list of ids for each user --> get a list of personal information for each ids by requesting an intranet site. 

In that, each arrow is a bunch of threads and I am limited in terms of how many threads I can launch in the meantime.

Comment: Slightly pedantic, but you don't need '>0' in that while loop - if you test a list in a scalar context like that it returns 'true' if there's elements in the list, and 'false' if there are not.

Comment: @Sobrique yes, I know.  It's a choice I made for clarity.  Just because you can omit something doesn't mean you should.  I mean, you could write it `map$_->join,threads->list(0)while threads->list`